# Start script on system startup (Ubuntu 16.04.1)

Tags: server, scripts, startup, cron, autostart

On my new Ubuntu system I tried to start a Bash script automatically on system start up.

I found a lot of posts and how-to's about it. 
so I tried to make it via Crontab:

- run `crontab -e`
- add `@reboot /cronjobs/demo.sh >> /cronjobs/cronLogs/demo.output`
- set execution permission to script with `sudo chmod +x /cronjobs/demo.sh`
- reboot system

The output was created, but the script will not execute.
So I tried another solution with `rc.local` file:

- run `sudo vi /etc/rc.local`
- added `/cronjobs/demo.sh || exit 1`
- reboot system

But my script doesn't run.
So I read that for reboot the script must be in `/etc/rc0.d/`. So I tried this:

- move the script with `mv /cronjobs/demo.sh /etc/rc0.d/K99_demo.sh`
- check permissions (all seems to be ok)
- reboot system

Same thing - script will not be executed.

So, what's my error? Why my script can't be executed?
I can execute my script if I run `./demo.sh` after i switched to the folder with `cd /cronjobs` . The script is a demo-file which simply creates a folder:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo demo output
mkdir /cronjobs/demofolder
```

*Edited: Replaced paths and filenames; added full content of `demo.sh` file*

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"the output was created, but the script will not execute"* please?

Comment: @steeldriver i mean, that the file `log.output` was created after system startup - with my echo i typed in `script.sh` to log something. But the script `script.sh` would not be executed (means that the `demofolder` wasn't created).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is using sudo powers create a file like this in `/etc/cron.d/`:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
@reboot   root    mkdir /cronjobs
@reboot   root    sleep 10
@reboot   root    mkdir /cronjobs/demofolder
```

This avoids the use of a script file altogether and works for all users regardless of their home directory name, ie /home/steve, /home/mary, etc.

#### Edit - Add `sleep 10`

For whatever reason cron is working too fast, or kernel is working too slow when making directories. An extra line `sleep 10` was necessary between the two `mkdir` lines.

You may not need 10 seconds in between the two make directory commands but 10 works on my system with an SSD.

#### Edit 2 - Make full directory path in one command

As per comments below a simpler method is to use:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
@reboot   root    mkdir -p -v /cronjobs/demofolder
```

- `-p` (long version `--parents`) tells `mkdir` to automatically create all directory parent levels if they don't exist.
- `-v` (long version `--verbose`) tells `mkdir` to print the names of all directories created.

Comment: yes. the file and folder names are not this what i used on my system. it is only a example how i used it - that you know what i have done ;)

Comment: If your question doesn't contain what you REALLY typed, how are we supposed to give a REAL answer?

Comment: I thought that the real paths and file names are not important for my question. The path and file names are correctly - without typo. And i only used other path and scriptnames - the call of it is the same. But if you need the real paths, i can edit my post with real paths and filenames.

Comment: I think it is best to include real commands and real error messages (if any) that are displayed after the real commands are entered.

Comment: Ok, then i will edit my first post. :)

Comment: If i understand this correctly: this file create a new cronjob - with root permissions - with no relation to a specific user - but start the script with root-permissions. correct? It seems to be a new logic to add a script to startup.
But why my two solutions doesn't work?

Comment: You are correct the cron job runs on boot with root-permissions regardless of who signs on. I've just tested the answer I posted with a different command for my own project an hour ago and it works. Why your previous attempts do not work would require experimentation on my part.

Comment: Sry for late response - i had tried your example, but on reboot the script wouldn't create a new folder. So i think the `@reboot` thing on crontab wouldn't work correctly.
Maybe the better solution is to start a script on reboot with `supervisor`?

Comment: @devKyrios Just noticed on my system `mkdir` has to be called twice. I've updated the cron job accordingly.

Comment: I had modified the script with your example. Nothing happend. I added a output to it but the output wasn't created.

Comment: @devKyrios Indeed I had simply taken a script that worked and modified it without testing. After testing I noticed only the `/cronjobs` directory was created and the `/cronjobs/demofolder` sub-directory was not. After experimenting, rebooting and logging many times I discovered the `sleep 10` command was necessary (on my system) and added it to the answer. Very strange but whatever works works.

Comment: thx for your time and your great support.
If i start this with only one mkdir, this one folder wouldn't be created. So i don't think that your solution with sleep will solve my problem :)

Comment: One` mkdir` works great, it's when there are two in a row I need to put the sleep in between to slow things down. If you already have a `/cronjobs` folder you can remove that make directory line and the sleep line.

Comment: Maybe my answere wasn't clear :) I had create this file so than you desribe it (only with one mkdir to create only one folder in '/cronjobs'. This folder '/cronjobs' exist. I reboot the server, but no new folder will be create in the folder '/cronjobs'. So i think i missed a step or something for a functional reboot job.

Comment: You can use `mkdir -p /cronjobs/demofolder` to make a directory and create all necessary directories to make the whole path exist. It also won't treat "already exists" as an error - it will complete with a success exit code if the entire path already exists.

Comment: @doug65536 You are correct. I had learned that also after posting this answer. In Dec 2016 I had just used bash for a few months. Thank you.

Comment: @doug65536 sry for late answer - doesn't saw that this thread has new answers. Your tipp solved my problem! Thank you a lot!