# How to auto-start Apache & MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04 on system startup?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, xampp

I'm totally new to Ubuntu (Linux). I'm just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and install XAMPP (lampp, apache, mysql) on it. They are running well, but not started when I'm start/ restart the system.

To start Apache every time I've to run the command :

```
quleiss@quleiss:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

My question is, is there any way that it will start automatically when I'm starting my system.

I'm googled for this but there are many solutions for **how to install Apache ?**, but not for **how to make auto-start Apache ?**.

I referred this question :
[Start script on system startup (Ubuntu 16.04.1)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843323/start-script-on-system-startup-ubuntu-16-04-1)

After running `sudo systemctl status apache2` command it will give this output :

> apache2.service Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
>   Active: inactive (dead)

Any kind of help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was there a requirement for the lampp stack provided by a 3rd party, rather than the standard `apt-get install` method? Just curious is all. If there was no specific requirement, then the standard is apt-get.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.  Please explain what you are suggesting. I'm totally new to Linux(Ubuntu).

Comment: Please run: `sudo systemctl status apache2` from the terminal and let me know what response you get, post into your question...

Comment: After running sudo systemctl status apache2 command it will give this output : apache2.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: @ganesh - you've used a non standard method to install Apache/Mysql. LAMP is an acronym for Linux/Apache/MySQL/PHP. Installing applications on Ubuntu, is not as convoluted as Windows. Instead of having to download apps from 3rd party sites like VLC, you install then with apt. Apache can be installed like this `apt-get install apache2`, etc

Comment: @ThatGuy I run apt-get install apache2, and and after that I run sudo systemctl status apache2 this command and it gives me this result : apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2017-02-25 11:53:22 IST; 6min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Comment: After that : Feb 25 11:53:22 quleiss apache2[21979]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: mak
Feb 25 11:53:22 quleiss apache2[21979]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: mak
Feb 25 11:53:22 quleiss apache2[21979]: no listening sockets available, shutting
Feb 25 11:53:22 quleiss apache2[21979]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Feb 25 11:53:22 quleiss apache2[21979]: Action 'start' failed.
Feb 25 11:53:22 quleiss apache2[21979]: The Apache error log may have

Comment: more infor
Feb 25 11:53:22 quleiss apache2[21979]:  *
Feb 25 11:53:22 quleiss apache2[22002]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apac
Feb 25 11:53:22 quleiss apache2[22002]:  *
Feb 25 11:53:22 quleiss systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `netstat -ntlp`?  It sounds like your original installation of LAMPP is still running.  If it is, you can run `killall apache2`, and it should close. Either that, or a reboot should do the trick.

Comment: Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1111/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      835/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1346/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      835/cupsd

Comment: @GaneshAher - `:::80 :::* LISTEN 1346/apache2` tells me apache is still running.  Have you deleted the original LAMPP folder in /opt?

Comment: No, not deleted LAMPP folder. Should I've to delete that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54315/discussion-between-thatguy-and-ganesh-aher).

Comment: Ok, you left the chat.  In that case, the official method is to install via tasksel: `sudo tasksel install lamp-server`, you can find the official cocumentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lamp-overview.html)

Comment: the output for sudo netstat -ntlp is : Active Internet connections (only servers) 
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State PID/Program name 
tcp 0 0 127.0.1.1:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1254/dnsmasq 
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:631 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 865/cupsd 
tcp6 0 0 ::1:631 :::* LISTEN 865/cupsd

Answer (score 2):

By default, one does not have to initialize or start `apache`,`php` and `MySQL` and related modules every time the system starts. These are started automatically when Ubuntu starts.

Under normal cases the user does not have to interfere and  the webserver starts automatically.

---

In case this is not happening, the probable causes might be :

- `apache` might be incorrectly configured (most likely).
- `php` configuration has error ( any syntax error will cause `php` loading to fail), subsequently might affect `apache`.
- If `MySQL` connection is needed for serving a page, and this connection fails (because of MySQL not running), then `apache` will fail to start. Important is to start `apache` after `MySQL`. [Question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/513401/apache2-not-starting-at-boot-even-if-set-up-in-runlevels)

---

You can try to reinstall LAMP stack and immediately test with a reboot.